# cmake for OpenDDS Project

Tags: build, cmake, data-distribution-service, opendds

looking for a standard CMakelist to build OpenDDS application (Simple Publisher/Subscriber). I am familiar with the Tutorials and everything is running fine with MPC to build the examples. I need to build my project with cmake. I m using OpenDDS 3.9.

I tried to make a CMakelist for the Stockquote Example on here:
http://opendds.org/about/articles/Article-Intro.html

My CMakelist looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3.0)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
project (publisher)
set(DDS_ROOT_DIR "home/ubuntu/OpenDDS-3.9")

set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories (${DDS_ROOT_DIR} "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers" "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/TAO" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

file (GLOB_RECURSE PUBLISHER_SRC *.cpp)
file (GLOB_RECURSE IDL_SRC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${PUBLISHER_SRC} ${IDL_SRC})

project (subscriber)

set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories (${DDS_ROOT_DIR} "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers" "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/TAO" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

file (GLOB_RECURSE SUBSCRIBER_SRC *.cpp)
file (GLOB_RECURSE IDL_SRC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)

add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} ${SUBSCRIBER_SRC} ${IDL_SRC})

# Adding DDS link_libraries
if (WIN32)
  file (GLOB OpenDDS_LIBS "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/lib/*d.dll")
  foreach (i ${OpenDDS_LIBS})
    get_filename_component (BASE_NAME_DLL ${i} NAME_WE)
    add_library (${BASE_NAME_DLL} SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_property (TARGET ${BASE_NAME_DLL} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/lib/${BASE_NAME_DLL}.dll")
    set_property (TARGET ${BASE_NAME_DLL} PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/lib/${BASE_NAME_DLL}.lib")
    target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${BASE_NAME_DLL})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:${BASE_NAME_DLL}> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
  endforeach()

  file (GLOB OpenDDS_LIBS "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/lib/*d.dll")
  foreach (i ${OpenDDS_LIBS})
    get_filename_component (BASE_NAME_DLL ${i} NAME_WE)
    add_library (${BASE_NAME_DLL} SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_property (TARGET ${BASE_NAME_DLL} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/lib/${BASE_NAME_DLL}.dll")
    set_property (TARGET ${BASE_NAME_DLL} PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/lib/${BASE_NAME_DLL}.lib")
    target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${BASE_NAME_DLL})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:${BASE_NAME_DLL}> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
  endforeach ()
elseif (UNIX)
  file (GLOB OpenDDS_LIBS "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/lib/*.so")
  foreach (i ${OpenDDS_LIBS})
    get_filename_component (BASE_NAME_DLL ${i} NAME_WE)
    add_library (${BASE_NAME_DLL} SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_property (TARGET ${BASE_NAME_DLL} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/lib/${BASE_NAME_DLL}.so")
    target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${BASE_NAME_DLL})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:${BASE_NAME_DLL}> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
  endforeach()
  file (GLOB OpenDDS_LIBS "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/lib/*.so")
  foreach (i ${OpenDDS_LIBS})
    get_filename_component (BASE_NAME_DLL ${i} NAME_WE)
    add_library (${BASE_NAME_DLL} SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_property (TARGET ${BASE_NAME_DLL} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${DDS_ROOT_DIR}/ACE_wrappers/lib/${BASE_NAME_DLL}.so")
    target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} ${BASE_NAME_DLL})
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different $<TARGET_FILE:${BASE_NAME_DLL}> $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)
  endforeach ()
endif ()
```

I got the adding DDS Link Libraries Section from the WTeam Blog. http://www.wteam.it/index.php/articles/the-hla-series/9-article/15-first-opendds-program

Currently i receive this error message if i'm using cmake --build:

> /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/DataWriterImpl_T.h: In instantiation of ‘void
>   OpenDDS::DCPS::DataWriterImpl_T::init(DDS::Topic_ptr,
>   OpenDDS::DCPS::TopicImpl*, const DDS::DataWriterQos&,
>   DDS::DataWriterListener_ptr, const StatusMask&,
>   OpenDDS::DCPS::DomainParticipantImpl*, OpenDDS::DCPS::PublisherImpl*,
>   DDS::DataWriter_ptr) [with MessageType = Messenger::Message;
>   DDS::Topic_ptr = DDS::Topic*; DDS::DataWriterListener_ptr =
>   DDS::DataWriterListener*; DDS::StatusMask = unsigned int;
>   DDS::DataWriter_ptr = DDS::DataWriter*]’:
>   /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/FilterEvaluator.h:142:10:   required from
>   here /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/DataWriterImpl_T.h:317:50: error:
>   incomplete type
>   ‘OpenDDS::DCPS::DataWriterImpl_T::MarshalTraitsType
>   {aka OpenDDS::DCPS::MarshalTraits}’ used in nested
>   name specifier
>          if (MarshalTraitsType::gen_is_bounded_size()) {
>                                                     ^ /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/DataWriterImpl_T.h:323:54: error:
>   incomplete type
>   ‘OpenDDS::DCPS::DataWriterImpl_T::MarshalTraitsType
>   {aka OpenDDS::DCPS::MarshalTraits}’ used in nested
>   name specifier
>          if (MarshalTraitsType::gen_is_bounded_key_size()) {
>                                                         ^ /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/DataWriterImpl_T.h: In instantiation of
>   ‘DDS::ReturnCode_t
>   OpenDDS::DCPS::DataWriterImpl_T::enable_specific() [with
>   MessageType = Messenger::Message; DDS::ReturnCode_t = int]’:
>   /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/FilterEvaluator.h:142:10:   required from
>   here /usr/local/include/dds/DCPS/DataWriterImpl_T.h:338:51: error:
>   incomplete type
>   ‘OpenDDS::DCPS::DataWriterImpl_T::MarshalTraitsType
>   {aka OpenDDS::DCPS::MarshalTraits}’ used in nested
>   name specifier
>          if (MarshalTraitsType::gen_is_bounded_size ())
>                                                      ^

Does anyone have an idea whats wrong or has a standard CMake for OpenDDS applications? Thank you very much for any help.

Cheers, 
Marcel

Comment: Support of CMake for your application build in OpenDDS upcoming very soon. Final changes and testing underway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDDS 3.14 will have cmake support, see https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/tree/master/tests/cmake_integration for unit tests using cmake.

Answer (score 0):

The example project on that website is bundled with OpenDDS under the 'examples/DCPS' folder. It contains a working build script, instructions etc.

Comment: The website gives directions for building the example by using Make Project Creator (MPC). OP wants to use CMake. In what way is a pointer to the MPC instructions an answer to the question?